# Aggregation 30days data in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, aggregation, spark-structured-streaming

I am using Spark Structured Streaming to calculate the monthly amount of a user. I am using the below code:

```py
df = spark
        .readStream
        .format('kafka')
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false")
        .load()


df1 = df.groupby('client_id', 'id', window(col('date'), "30 days"))
.agg(sum(col('amount')).alias('amount'), count(col('id')).alias('count'))

df1.selectExpr("CAST(client_id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
       .writeStream
       .format('kafka')
       ........
```

I observed that the output is not correct. For example:

*input*

```
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-01", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-15", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-25", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-26", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-27", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-28", "amount": 10.0}
{"client_id":"1", "id":"1", "date":"2022-08-29", "amount": 10.0}
```

*output*

```
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":10.0,"count":1}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":20.0,"count":2}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":30.0,"count":3}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":40.0,"count":4}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":50.0,"count":5}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":10.0,"count":1}
{"client_id":"1","id":"1","amount":20.0,"count":2}
```

The first input record was on "2022-08-01" with an amount of 10. So it should sum the amount for the next 30 days. So the final sum should be 70, but it is 50 and then 20. It is calculating the sum for the next 27 days. You can see that the "count" and "amount" is updated on "2022-08-28". It is not aggregating records for 30 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.window.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window), there's this 4th argument...

> **startTime : *str, optional***
> The offset with respect to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC with which to start window intervals. For example, in order to have hourly tumbling windows that start 15 minutes past the hour, e.g. 12:15-13:15, 13:15-14:15… provide *startTime* as *15 minutes*.

This means, that windows are fixed durations *since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC*, unless you specify some other `startTime` which must be an offset interval from this point in time.

If you use `window` function without the `startTime` specified and `windowDuration="30 days"`, you will get intervals divided into 30-day periods starting from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. In your case, I don't really understand why the line between two 30-day windows is on 2022-08-28, because for me it's on 2022-08-26:

```
{2022-07-27 00:00:00, 2022-08-26 00:00:00}
{2022-08-26 00:00:00, 2022-09-25 00:00:00}
```

Even though there is a difference in exact dates, but the logic is the same: 30-day windows are created fixed from some specific point in time.

If I specify `startTime="1 day"`, I get 30-day windows shifted:

```
{2022-07-28 00:00:00, 2022-08-27 00:00:00}
{2022-08-27 00:00:00, 2022-09-26 00:00:00}
```

Only by carefully choosing the `startTime` we can get time windows start at the date we want, but it will always be fixed until the next change of `startTime`.

---

To get what you intend, you could probably use `slideDuration` parameter of the `window` function and filtering based on aggregation result:

```py
df1 = (df
    .groupby('client_id', 'id', F.window('date', "30 days", "1 day"))
    .agg(F.sum('amount').alias('amount'), F.count('id').alias('count'))
    .filter((F.date_add(F.sort_array(F.collect_set('date'), False)[0], 1) == F.col("window.end")))
).selectExpr("CAST(client_id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
```

Comment: It will aggregate data per month. But I want to aggregate the amount on the bases of 30 days. It is like a rolling sum. for example, if a record is for 2022-09-10 then it should sum the data till 2022-10-09

Comment: Thank you so much @ZygD. It is working fine. The only issue I found is that you added a filter condition on the timestamp which will not work due to minute/hour/milisec. And if I convert it into date then window.end is the next day. for example, I added an event. The event time is  `2022-09-05 11:21:22.938` so spark is creating a window of `{2022-08-07 00:00:00, 2022-09-06 00:00:00}`  I am not sure it default behaviour but solution is working like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help. The next day which you see (`2022-09-06 00:00:00`) is exclusive, so it actually does not include this final timestamp value, however `2022-09-05 23:59:59` would be included.